# How do i make permanent Symbols or change Symbols afterwards in a Terminal in C

Tags: c, terminal, console

Hey so I want to make a game like Snake or Dwarf Fortress in a console/terminal. I want to print a game field with *'s and other symbols and change them without moving to console upwards. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a library like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). It is meant for building console-based UIs.